# The added text is not being displayed in the Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to write some values in .xlsx workbook (workbook already present), but I am unable to do it. In the below given code I am trying to write the word "PASS". As per my knowledge `cell.setCellValue("PASS")` is setting up the value for the cell, but when I open the .xlsx sheet the value is not displayed. I used `System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue())` to find if the value is assigned to the cell or not, it is printing the value as PASS.

```
public static void writeResultInExcel() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{
    int testScript=0;
    Cell cell = null;
    fi = new File("D:/Selenium/Excel/Example.xlsx");
    fis = new FileInputStream(fi);  
    W = WorkbookFactory.create(fi);
    Sheet sh = W.getSheetAt(testScript);
    cell=sh.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("PASS");
    fis.close();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fi");
        W.write(fos);
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the FileOutputStream. It should then release anything associated with it.

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fi);
    W.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did closing the FileOutputStream and executed the code now it is giving the following exception "java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000000000, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0". Seems like my file is really not a .xlsx file, how do i create a .xlsx file which would allow me to do some actions on it... Thank u again.

Answer (score 0):

You are writting the xls in another location ("fi"): FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fi");
Your code should be something like this:

`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/Selenium/Excel/Example.xlsx);`